# GWT: get backing object for row by id in table

Tags: gwt, gwt-celltable, multipleselection

Is there any simple way to get the object, used to render given row in CellTable, by index of the row?

I am using AsyncDataProvider, and don't want to remember lists of data objects, returned from the server. Also I am using MultiSelectionModel, so several items could be selected there and I need to track out which one was clicked last.

I know the index of last clicked row, so I need to get the object, corresponding to the row, somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`getVisibleItem`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/AbstractHasData.html#getVisibleItem%28int%29)? possibly combined with `getPageStart` if you're using paging and you only know the *absolute index*.

For your use-case, maybe you could use a customized selection model whose `setSelected` tracks the last change.